# My code is not showing results in the index.html file

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="if=edge"
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style media="text/css">
    @media screen
    and (min-device-width: 1200px)
    and (max-device-width: 1600px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    }
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 320px)
    and (max-device-width: 480px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    }
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 768px)
    and (max-device-width: 1024px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    }
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h3>
        Hello
      </h3>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

I only want the code to show one word in h3. I can't see anything on my screen. Nothing shows. I created this content on atom editor. Is there a certain package I have to download. Is there anything wrong with the code? I am lost. I am currently trying to create a customized email.

Comment: You need to close `<style>` with `</style>` and it will work: https://repl.it/repls/PlasticWebbedWrapper#index.html

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in `<style>` you need to close it

it's so easy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="if=edge"
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style media="text/css">
    @media screen
    and (min-device-width: 1200px)
    and (max-device-width: 1600px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    }
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 320px)
    and (max-device-width: 480px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    }
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 768px)
    and (max-device-width: 1024px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h3>
        Hello
      </h3>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` tag itself.